# Can i use three different server as (https, socket, redis) with feathersJS in node?

Tags: node.js, feathersjs

I want to start all server's as following manner. And how to pass argument parameter.

```
https_server.js // that handle's REST API call
app.js // socket server that handle runtime events
redis.js // redis server
```

Answer (score 0):

We released a [new feature](https://github.com/feathersjs/feathers-socketio/pull/69) in [feathers-socketio](https://github.com/feathersjs/feathers-socketio/) that allows to run the [Socket.io server on a separate port](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/socketio.html#appconfiguresocketioport-options-callback) like this:

```
const feathers = require('feathers');
const socketio = require('feathers-socketio');

const app = feathers()
  .configure(socketio(3031));

app.listen(3030);
```

Now you will have to separate servers, one that handles REST connections on port `3030` and one for websocket connection on `3031`.

Comment: thank you,
 But when you changes somethings socket related problem  or issues and code update to the server then we need to restart server file Right !!
So i think we can't able to restart one of server.

Comment: What do you mean? On code updates there is not really an easy way around restarting the server.

Comment: Suppose when i will change my middleware module and add some functions to it.
then, Need to server file restart ?

like using forever server_file

Comment: so, in this case all connected users disconnect and connect again while restart nodejs server.
there is possible to i will restart only socket or http server as with forever restart file-name in featherJS.

Comment: when it's not valid to implement above things to the nodeJs with featherJs, then there is any frameworks to build game with nodejs.

Comment: That has nothing to do with the framework (and your original question). If you change a file in NodeJS you have to restart the server unless you use something like [Webpacks hot module replacement](https://webpack.github.io/docs/hot-module-replacement.html).